# How to add a pop-up picture in google tables? When I hover my mouse over this cell, a pop-up window appears with the enlarged image

Tags: image, popup

I need to add a pop-up picture in google tables. 
For example, I put an image in a cell. The image becomes the size of a cell, but when I hover my mouse over this cell, a pop-up window appears with the enlarged image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a class css hover:

```
a:hover {
width: 200%;
height: 200%
}
```

tell me if im right